# Converting quaternion to euler without losing information.

Tags: quaternions, angle, orientation

I have a 6DOF sensor outputting a quaternion and I need to convert the quaternion into euler angles. The problem is that when I use the following equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \phi \\ \theta \\ \psi \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} Y \\ P \\ R \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{atan2}\left( -2q_1q_2 + 2q_0q_3,\; q_0^2 + q_1^2 - q_3^2 - q_2^2 \right) \\
\mathrm{asin}\left( 2q_1q_3 + 2q_0q_2 \right) \\
\mathrm{atan2}\left( -2q_2q_3 + 2q_0q_1,\; q_3^2 - q_2^2 - q_1^2 + q_0^2 \right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The output is limited to +-90 degrees because of the inverse trigonometric functions.

What set of equations should I use to convert quaternion to euler without losing information.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why exactly do you need Euler angles? Converting TO Euler angles is a big step backwards, performance-wise

Comment: To stabilize a quadcopter.

Comment: Don't most sensors that offer quaternion output also allow you to toggle  it to Euler angles?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MPU-6050 which can be configured to process the angle and return a better result (but in quaternion).

Comment: Seconding what Peter Sheldrick said. I would think *atan2* gives you a full 360 degree range. Either from $0$ to $2\pi$ or from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ all according to how it is implemented. Not sure about pitch though? Does it make sense for pitch to be outside $\pm\pi/2$?

Comment: @VasilKalchev So, what you mean to say is that whatever stabilization mechanism you have only is configured to accept Euler angles?

Comment: I am using the sensored angles as the inputs of PID regulators (one for each angle). And I am setting the setpoints manually.

Comment: @VasilKalchev I don't know what any of that means, but I just think it's unlikely that the sensor gives you more accurate quaternions than Euler angles. But it sounds like you are saying that you contribute something during the conversion that might do that.

Comment: Yes, the stabilization algorithm needs euler angles. The quaternion is accurate (there are a lot of hardware and algorithm specifics that we can go into, but they are off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly askew-topic, if not off-topic, but let me just give you the comment section of my code for the function whose input is a quaternion and whose output is the corresponding $3\times3$ rotation matrix. The "Notes:" section explains the requisite algebra.

```
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    qmatrix ( QUAT q )
 * Purpose:     returns 3x3 rotation matrix corresponding to quaternion q
 *              ( can just be called as qmatrix(qrotate(axis,theta))
 *                for rotation matrix around axis through theta )
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   q (I)           QUAT q for which a rotation matrix
 *                              is to be constructed
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Returns:     ( double * )    3x3 rotation matrix, stored row-wise
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o The matrix constructed from input q = q0+q1*i+q2*j+q3*k is:
 *                    (q0²+q1²-q2²-q3²)    2(q1q2-q0q3)     2(q1q3+q0q2)
 *                Q  =   2(q2q1+q0q3)   (q0²-q1²+q2²-q3²)   2(q2q3-q0q1)
 *                       2(q3q1-q0q2)      2(q3q2+q0q1)  (q0²-q1²-q2²+q3²)
 *            o The returned matrix is stored row-wise, i.e., explicitly
 *                --------- first row ----------
 *                qmatrix[0] = (q0²+q1²-q2²-q3²)
 *                       [1] =    2(q1q2-q0q3)
 *                       [2] =    2(q1q3+q0q2)
 *                --------- second row ---------
 *                       [3] =    2(q2q1+q0q3)
 *                       [4] = (q0²-q1²+q2²-q3²)
 *                       [5] =    2(q2q3-q0q1)
 *                --------- third row ----------
 *                       [6] =    2(q3q1-q0q2)
 *                       [7] =    2(q3q2+q0q1)
 *                       [8] = (q0²-q1²-q2²+q3²)
 *            o qmatrix maintains a static buffer of 128 3x3 matrices
 *              returned to the caller one at a time. So you may issue
 *              128 qmatrix() calls and continue using all returned matrices.
 *              The 129th call re-uses the memory used by the 1st call, etc.
 * ======================================================================= */
```